# Download the attachment with zapier?

Tags: automation, zapier, zapier-cli

I need to create a zap in Zappier to automate a task. Below are steps

1. Create a trigger which will check if an email is received that has an attachment.
2. Create a task which will download the attachment from email & encode into binary. (I need to create a new zap through CLI i think ).

I am not sure how do I fetch the attachment

Comment: What is the email client you are using?

Comment: @MichaelCase I am using now gmail client

Comment: Thats good, Zapier has a well defined Gmail integration that you will be able to configure to suit your needs. Once the file is encoded where do you want it to end up?

Comment: I have one query. How can i get the attachment from gmail & use it for encoding. I want to download get attachment from gmail & encode it.

Comment: If you are familiar with programming in either Python or Javascript zapier offers a code module that you could use to achieve something like this. How you go about it sort of depends on what you want to do with the file once it is encoded though...

Comment: seems like Gmail restricts to read email content on zap. So i tried with dropbox. I downloaded the attachment